# Strategies to speed up access to databases when working with columns containing massive amounts of data (spatial columns, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-design, postgis

First things first, I am an amateur, self-taught ruby programmer who came of age as a novice engineer in the age of super-fast computers where program efficiency was not an issue in the early stages of my primary GIS software development project. This technical debt is starting to tax my project and I want to speed up access to this lumbering GIS database.

Its a postgresql database with a postgis extension, controlled inside of rails, which immediately creates efficiency issues via the object-ification of database columns when accessing and/or manipulating database records with one or many columns containing text or spatial data easily in excess of 1 megabyte per column.

Its extremely slow now, and it didn't used to be like this.

One strategy: I'm considering building child tables of my large spatial data tables (state, county, census tract, etc) so that when I access the tables I don't have to load the massive spatial columns every time I access the objects. But then doing spatial queries might be difficult on a parent table's children. Not sure exactly how I would do that but I think its possible.

Maybe I have too many indexes. I have a lot of spatial indexes. Do additional spatial indexes from tables I'm not currently using slow down my queries? How about having too many for one table?

These tables have a massive amount of columns. Maybe I should remove some columns, or create parent tables for the columns with massive serialized hashes?

There are A LOT of tables I don't use anymore. Is there a reason other than tidiness to remove these unused tables? Are they slowing down my queries? Simply doing a #count method on some of these tables takes TIME.

PS:
- Looking back at this 8 hours later, I think what I'm equally trying to understand is how many of the above techniques are completely USELESS when it comes to optimizing (rails) database performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to read all of the columns of the table. Just read the ones you need.

You can:

```
MyObject.select(:id, :col1, :col2).where(...)
```

... and the omitted columns are not read.

If you try to use a method that needs one of the columns you've omitted then you'll get an ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (Rails 4), but you presumably know when you're going to need them or not.

The inclusion of large data sets in the table is going to be a noticeable problem from the database side if you have full table scans, and then you might consider moving these data to other tables.

If you only use Rails to read and write the large data columns, and don't use PostgreSQL functions on them, you might be able to compress the data on write and decompress on read. Override the getter and setter methods by using write_attribute and read_attribute, compressing and decompressing (respectively of course) the data.

Comment: Oh....so I can take text that's x characters and reduce it to 1/100(x) characters? or something like that? Honestly, that has never occurred to me until now. Never dealt with compression at so direct a level. Interesting concept. I wonder how many times I could compress a set of characters, and perhaps more importantly if I could compress spatial columns....and if so, still be able to query on them...

Comment: Might be worth a test, just to see what the effect on storage would be. I'd only do it if it was a problem that the table was too large in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing. If you are using postgres to store such large chucks of data in single fields consider storing it as Array, JSON or Hstore fields. If you index it using the gin index types so you can search effectively within a given field.

Comment: I'm researching hstore for the large text columns. Right now they're serialized json